# Creating a private chat between a key using a node.js and socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, chat

How do I emit a message to all users in a private chat sharing a conversation_id using node.js and socket.io?

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
conversations = {};

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.sendfile('/');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

socket.on('send message', function (data) {

    var conversation_id = data.conversation_id;

    if (conversation_id in conversations) {

        console.log (conversation_id + ' is already in the conversations object');

        // emit the message [data.message] to all connected users in the conversation

    } else {
        socket.conversation_id = data;
        conversations[socket.conversation_id] = socket;

        conversations[conversation_id] = data.conversation_id;

        console.log ('adding '  + conversation_id + ' to conversations.');

        // emit the message [data.message] to all connected users in the conversation

    }
})
});

server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65787883/3904109 : have a look here also it might help

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You have to create a room with `conversation_id` and make users to subscribe to that room, so that you can emit a private message to that room it by,

**client**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://ip:port');

socket.emit('subscribe', conversation_id);

socket.emit('send message', {
    room: conversation_id,
    message: "Some message"
});

socket.on('conversation private post', function(data) {
    //display data.message
});
```

**Server**

```
socket.on('subscribe', function(room) {
    console.log('joining room', room);
    socket.join(room);
});

socket.on('send message', function(data) {
    console.log('sending room post', data.room);
    socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('conversation private post', {
        message: data.message
    });
});
```

Here is the docs and example for creating a room, subscribing to the room and Emit message to a room:

1. [Socket.io Rooms](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/)
2. [Socket.IO subscribe to multiple channels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16475058/453486)
3. [Socket.io rooms difference between broadcast.to and sockets.in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6873607/453486)

Comment: Great, thanks, it works perfectly. I changed `socket.broadcast.to()` to  `io.sockets.in()` so that it includes the emitting socket.

Comment: this helped me a lot https://divillysausages.com/2015/07/12/an-intro-to-socket-io/ , see Sending a message to another user

Answer (score 17):

SURE: Simply,

This is what you need :

```
 io.to(socket.id).emit("event", data);
```

whenever a user joined to the server,socket details will be generated including ID.This is the ID really helps to send a message to particular people.

first we need to store all the socket.ids in array,

```
   var people={};

   people[name] =  socket.id;
```

here name is the reciever name. Example:

```
  people["ccccc"]=2387423cjhgfwerwer23;
```

So, now we can get that socket.id with the reciever name whenever we are sending message:

for this we need to know the recievername.You need to emit reciever name to the server.

final thing is:

```
  socket.on('chat message', function(data){
 io.to(people[data.reciever]).emit('chat message', data.msg);
 });
```

Hope this works well for you.!!Good Luck