# Socket.io - Privare chat between two people

Tags: socket.io

I just began using socket.io and have already familiarized myself with things like `socket.brodcast.emit()` function, `namespaces` and `rooms`.

Now the next step is private messaging, and believe me when I say I have literally searched the entire internet for a solution, but have ended up getting nothing out of it. So I would like to know if anyone knows a way for me to use private message messaging in socket.io

Comment: [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619015/creating-a-private-chat-between-a-key-using-a-node-js-and-socket-io) [result](http://google.com/search?q=private+chat+in+socket.io)

Comment: You can emit events directly from one socket to another. The trick, then, is pairing sockets up with one another. Is it meant to be a random conversation, or are sockets supposed to choose who they're talking to?