# PHP MySQL socket.io fetch messages

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I'm making a private messaging app

PHP->MySQL

I store the messages in a mysql database, and whenever needed can be downloaded.

I'm new to socket.io and not sure how to do it correctly.

---

Let's say there are two users in the same chatRoom

```
userId   | nickName      | chatId   | 
---------|---------------|----------|
1        | "fred"        | 1        |
2        | "john"        | 1        |
```

ChatRooms:

```
chatId   | chatName      | 
---------|---------------|
1        | "coolChat"    |
```

// (and also I have a table for the chatMessages)

When user sends a message, the following happens:

**The sendMessage.php:**

```
$qry = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO chatMessages (chatId, userId, message) VALUES(:chatId, :userId, :message)');
$qry->bindParam(':chatId', $chatId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$qry->bindParam(':userId', $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$qry->bindParam(':message', $message, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$qry->execute();

if ($qry->rowCount() > 0) {

   // let's say I collected all the users in the same chatRoom:
   $chatRoomUsers = array(1, 2);

   // Successfully inserted into the database, should somehow
   // push the message with socket.io to another users in the same chatRoom
   for($i=0; $i<count($chatRoomUsers); $i++){
       // socket.push(toUserId: $chatRoomUsers[$i], inChatRoom: $chatId, message: $message);
   }

}
```

**The socket file so far:**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var sockets = {};

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);

  });
});


http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

var people = {};
socket.on('join', function(name){
  people[socket.id] = name;
  console.log(people);
});
```

So is there a way to send messages only to userId's in the same chatRoom?

Comment: There are several ways to do it. But your questions is way _too broad_ to explain it all. It would require writing half a book. Also your question doesn't show anything you've tried yourself to accomplish your goal. Only what you did to prepare for it. Basicly, if your question starts with: _How do I..?_, SO is the wrong place to ask. If your question starts with: _I'm trying to accomplish ... I tried this, it didn't work, what went wrong?_, SO is the place to be.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619015/creating-a-private-chat-between-a-key-using-a-node-js-and-socket-io and also google for `socket io private chat`

Comment: That being said: One way to do it would be to append a box id at the beginning of each message and split the message string serverside so you have it available to you. Don't try to create "real chatrooms", but instead have only 1 room where messages are filtered based on the box id. So all other messages are still there, but simply invisble because they have a different box id.